# what is the difference between static structure and normal structure?

Tags: c++, c, static, structure

I have a Code example here.

```
struct node { 
        int data;
        struct node *link;
    };
    static struct node *first = NULL;
```

It would be great if someone could throw some light on my below questions about the usage of the word static.

1. What does the keyword static do in the above code?
2. what is the difference between normal structure and static structure?

Comment: There is no `static struct` in your code. It's just `static` instance of `struct node`.

Comment: @iammilind: it's not even that, it's an instance of `struct node*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It creates a static pointer to a `node` and initializez it to `NULL`.

The variable definition can have multiple meanings:

```
static struct node *first = NULL;
```

If defined outside of a method, it gives `first` **internal linkage**. It can only be used inside the defining module.

But you can also find that line inside a method:

```
void foo()
{ 
    static struct node *first = NULL;
}
```

The variable is a method-scoped variable residing in static storage. It is initialized to `NULL` once and all subsequent changes persist between calls to the function.

Comment: The latter case is called a variable with "function scope and static storage duration", not "global method-scoped".

Answer (score 5):

It means that this variable may not be used outside this module.

E.g. - you cannot reference this pointer from another file using

```
extern struct node *first;
```

An important note is that the struct is not static, only `first` which is a pointer to such structure is static.

Comment: It can also be a static variable inside a method.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - true, didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't affect the definition of the structure itself. It just means that the particular *instance* of the structure, named `first` here, has internal linkage.

Comment: Don't you mean internal linkage?

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword for a global variable makes the variable local to the module where it is defined. I.e. you cannot access it from another module.

If the static variable is defined within a function it keeps the variable alive and updated between calls to this function.

Answer (score 0):

When modifying a variable, the static keyword specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends) and initializes it to 0 unless another value is specified. When modifying a variable or function at file scope, the static keyword specifies that the variable or function has internal linkage (its name is not visible from outside the file in which it is declared).

A variable declared static in a function retains its state between calls to that function.

When modifying a data member in a class declaration, the static keyword specifies that one copy of the member is shared by all instances of the class. When modifying a member function in a class declaration, the static keyword specifies that the function accesses only static members.

Static data members of classes must be initialized at file scope.

In recursive code, a static object or variable is guaranteed to have the same state in different instances of a block of code.

The members of a union cannot be declared as static. An anonymous union declared globally must be explicitly declared static.

Objects and variables defined outside all blocks have static lifetime and external linkage by default. A global object or variable that is explicitly declared as static has internal linkage.

Comment: **Static doesn't mean that.** In fact, it's allocated in static storage, not on the heap or stack.